# Passing data from app to app without one app installed

Tags: ios, custom-url

I know it's possible to pass data from one app to another app on the same device using custom url schemes or protocol handlers.

Is it possible to pass data from one app to another app that isn't installed? Ideally the user would be taken to the app store for the uninstalled app, the user would download the uninstalled app, and the custom url scheme from the original app would still pass the data to the newly installed app.

Is that possible?

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about, comparable to custom URL schemes, meaning a little of text ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass data from one app to another app that isn't
>   installed?

**YES**.

using the `x-callback` parameters, we can ask the target app to call us back on our own URLs, even handling **success** and **error** scenarios.Sort of like custom HTTP headers, these callback parameters are identified with an x- namespace:

**x-error** : URL to open if the requested action generates an error in the target app. This URL will be open with at least the parameters “errorCode=code&errorMessage=message. If x-error is not present, and a error occurs, it is assumed the target app will report the failure to the user and remain in the target app.

**x-source** : The friendly name of the source app calling the action.

**x-success** : If the action in the target method is intended to return a result to the source app, the x-callback parameter should be included and provide a URL to open to return to the source app. On completion of the action, the target app will open this URL, possibly with additional parameters tacked on to return a result to the source app. If x-success is not provided, it is assumed that the user will stay in the target app on successful completion of the action.